# is adding a function in another file to a project needs modifying makefile?

Tags: c, makefile

Is using a function defined in another file (example.[ch]) which is placed in project directory (and included with #include "example.h") needs editing project Makefile?
i tried using my function in part of net-snmp project and faced linker errors.
the error is:

```
./.libs/libnetsnmpmibs.so: undefined reference to `snmpget'
```

the nodeFunc.c look like this:

```
#include <net-snmp/net-snmp-config.h>
#include <net-snmp/net-snmp-includes.h>
#include <net-snmp/agent/net-snmp-agent-includes.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "NodeFunc.h"
int snmpget(char* remoteip, short remoteport,char* community,int *len,char* str)
{
....using some net-snmp functions to get a certain object from a remote host....
}
```

and i used the snmpget function in my main file like this:

```
...
snmpget(remIP,161,remComm,&lenth,ansstr);
...
```

Comment: Depends on the Makefile. If the Makefile is set up to compile all the .c files in the project directory, then no. If it has a list of files and only compiles those files, then yes.

Comment: you also have a new header file.  The makefile, if automatically generating dependencies, will never have to specifically mention the new header file.  Otherwise, the new header file will need to be mentioned as a dependency for every *.c file that #include's it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not the addition of a function that would require modification on the makefile, but rather the addition of the source file itself.  If in the makefile the source file is not already referenced as a compilation target and its object file is not a link dependency, then it will not be included in the build.

Inclusion in the build is not the purpose of the `#include` directive.  That merely *includes* the content of the .h file in the source file in order that the compiler has visibility of the declarations; it does not involve the .c file containing the definitions - that must be separately compiled and linked which is the role of the makefile in this case.

Comment: Thnx. added NodeFunc to the objects list ans compilation was successful.

Comment: Note that the addition of a .h file creates a dependency that must be made explicit in the makefile. Should the .h file change, the dependents must be recompiled.